# Alienware 13 R3 experiences huge FPS drop after it ran out of battery once

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Last night my laptop (Alienware 13 R3) ran out of battery whilst I was gaming.

When I restarted my laptop with a charger plugged in, I noticed that the game was getting really low FPS. Turns out that all games are getting very low FPS right now. Now my laptop is fully charged but I'm seeing the same problem. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: I looked around online a bit, and found one person who had the same issue. It turns out they had stealth mode on. Do you happen to have stealth mode turned on?

Comment: Ensure that the power mode is set to high performance and not power saver. This can be done by right clicking on the battery in the bottom right near the clock and changing settings for "on battery"

Comment: @DrZoo could you link me to the thread?  I'm not even aware that stealth mode is a thing.

Comment: [Here](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/5836265263?page=2) is where I saw it. I just read up on how to enable stealth mode and I'm unsure if it's just a thing for the m17 or what. I steer clear of Alienware so I'm not really sure if yours has stealth mode or not. I'd check your power settings like Narzard stated. Also test to see if it works fine when unplugged, or if you have the same slow FPS.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by downloading Nvidia GeForce Experience and use it to download the latest Nvidia driver.